# Blackberry: opening ConnectionFactory too many times?

Tags: blackberry

I'm not entirely sure how to use ConnectionFactory properly, but here is my ImageThread example which invokes ConnectionFactory every time there is an image, which there are a bunch on any given screen.

```
public class ImageThread extends Thread {
private String url;
private HttpConnection httpConn;
private InputStream is;
private JSONArray array;
private Bitmap image;
private ImageThreadCallback c;


private static boolean hasImageCache = false;
private static MultiMap imageCache;

public ImageThread(String url, ImageThreadCallback c, String ident){
    System.out.println("Connection begin!");
    this.url = url;
    this.c = c;

}

public void notifyUs(){
    this.c.update(image);
}


public void run(){

    myConnectionFactory connFact = new myConnectionFactory();
    ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;

    connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connection factory!");
    if(connDesc != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection not null!");
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
        try {
            httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        is = null;



        try
        {
            final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println("Connection in run!");
                     // Get InputConnection and read the server's response
                    InputConnection inputConn = (InputConnection) httpConn;
                    try {
                        is = inputConn.openInputStream();
                        System.out.println("Connection got inputstream!");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    byte[] data = null;
                    try {
                        data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
                        System.out.println("Connection got data!");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                     EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length);

                    image = hai.getBitmap();
                    notifyUs();


                }

            });
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

}
```

I know the example is the same as the examples, but should ConnectionFactory be called every instance of ImageThread? I ask this question because my app all of a sudden loses connection, randomly, while using it. The input/output icon ceases to flicker. I'm thinking it could be a misuse of ConnectionFactory?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to create a new instance unless you want to change connection preferences, like connection mode or timeout.

The loss of connectivity seems a different issue to me. Reusing collection means that you are going to save heap memory, but I don't think it is related to the other thing. You could try to debug on device and see what HTTP error code do you get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are performing I/O operations on Application's event thread.
When you use invokeLater( Runnable r ), r is executed on Application's event thread. In all probability, the Blackberry runtime would kill the application.

As far as I see your code, you just don't have to create the anonymous inner class of Runnable that is passed to invokeLater(). You can simply do this:

```
if(connDesc != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection not null!");
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
        try {
            httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        is = null;



        try
        {
            final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                   System.out.println("Connection in run!");
                     // Get InputConnection and read the server's response
                    InputConnection inputConn = (InputConnection) httpConn;
                    try {
                        is = inputConn.openInputStream();
                        System.out.println("Connection got inputstream!");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    byte[] data = null;
                    try {
                        data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
                        System.out.println("Connection got data!");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                     EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length);

                    image = hai.getBitmap();
                    notifyUs();
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Though, I find other issues with the code, it would be okay if you make the correction I mentioned.